# How can I avoid using more than a single "break" statement in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, sonarqube, break

For code quality reason, I would like to refactor my code a little bit in order to use only one `break` statement in my loop. But I am not sure I can do this the way SonarQube is aking me...

Here's my code :

```
for (Integer integer: integerKey.keySet()) {
    if (map.containsKey(integerKey.get(integer))) {
        TypeValue value = map.get(integerKey.get(integer));
        sb.append(integerKey.get(integer)).append(":");
        sb.append(encodeValue(value));
        sb.append("|");
        if (integerKey.get(integer).equals(min)) {
            break;
        }
    } else if (integerKey.get(integer) <= min){
        TypeValue value = map.get(min);
        sb.append(min).append(":");
        sb.append(encodeValue(value));
        sb.append("|");
        break;
    } else {
        sb.append(integerKey.get(integer)).append(":");
        sb.append("0");
        sb.append("|");
    }
}
```

I would like to do the same thing but using only one `break` but I am not sure I can write only one `if` condition in this case instead of `if-elseif-else`.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: it's more efficient to iterate over the entrySet, if you need the key and the value, as you can avoid to lookup (Map.get).

Comment: Additional side note: `integerKey.get(integer)` could be "cached" anyways so you don't have to do the lookup multiple times per iteration. Best would be to use the entry set and just get key and value of the entry, just as Puce already said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a variable for the break-condition and include it into the for-loop condition:

```
boolean endLoop = false;
for (Iterator<Integer> keys = integerKey.keySet(); keys.hasNext() && !endLoop; ) {
    Integer integer = keys.next();
    if (map.containsKey(integerKey.get(integer))) {
        ...
        if (integerKey.get(integer).equals(min)) {
            endLoop = true;
        }
    } else if (integerKey.get(integer) <= min){
        ...
        endLoop = true;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

or declare a local variable in the loop which is set to true if the loop should left with a break:

```
for (Integer integer: integerKey.keySet()) {
    boolean endLoop = false;
    if (map.containsKey(integerKey.get(integer))) {
        ...
        if (integerKey.get(integer).equals(min)) {
            endLoop = true;
        }
    } else if (integerKey.get(integer) <= min){
        ...
        endLoop = true;
    } else {
        ...
    }
    if (endloop)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes I see, that is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to use only one break, then you could set a boolean variable and test it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

@hacks4life, the answer you selected is definitely the one you were asking for but it is not the one you should get from an "improve the quality of code" point of view (After all, you did add the SonarQube tag to your question which kind of implies you are interested in code quality).

Neither your code snippet nor the one from the selected answer are easy to read nor to maintain. And the main is reason is that several code logics are mixed into each other (aka. [Spaghetti_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)).

If you could split exit conditions from string concatenation logic, the question would be irrelevant and your code would be both easier to maintain and would have neither multiple break statement neither a mutable control flow variable (which both are code smells).